# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'login' available as request attribute

Tags: spring, exception, spring-mvc, spring-form

I am getting the following exception while implementing a spring mvc program with form handling. Could you help me with this?

Stacktrace of the exception is as follows:

```
    Dec 30, 2013 11:50:28 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag doStartTag
    SEVERE: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'login' available as request attribute
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'login' available as request attribute
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:117)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.login_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(login_jsp.java:187)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.login_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(login_jsp.java:133)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:88)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Login.jsp - This is the jsp file that throws the exception

```
                            <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
                                pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
                            <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
                            <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
                            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
                            <html>
                            <head>
                            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
                            <title>Chronos Login</title>


                            <link href="/chronos/resources/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
                            <script>
                                function submitOnClick(formName){
                                    document.forms[formName].submit();
                                }
                            </script>
                            </head>

                            <body>
                            <form:form id="loginForm" method="POST" action="login.html" modelAttribute="login">
                                <div id="container">
                                    <div id = "left">
                                      <div id="row">
                                        <label for="username">Username:</label>
                                        <form:input type="text" id="username" path="username"/>
                                        </div>
                                      <div id="row">
                                        <label for="password">Password:</label>
                                        <form:input type="password" id="password" path="password" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="message"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="submit" onClick="submitOnClick('loginForm')">        
                                        <!--<input type="submit" value=">">-->
                                        <div id="arrow">></div>
                                    </div>    
                                    <div class="clear"></div>
                                </div>
                            </form:form>
                            </body>
                            </html>
```

BaseController.java - the controller class, that simply prints the user name and password when `login.jsp` is submitted

```
                            package com.chronos.controller;

                            import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
                            import org.springframework.ui.Model;
                            import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
                            import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
                            import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
                            import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
                            import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

                            import com.chronos.beans.LoginBean;

                            @Controller
                            @RequestMapping("login.html")
                            public class BaseController {   

                                @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
                                public String login(Model model) {
                                    System.out.println("here");
                                    model.addAttribute("login", new LoginBean());
                                    return "login";
                                }

                                @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
                                public String loginValidate(@ModelAttribute("login")LoginBean loginBean, ModelMap model) {
                                    System.out.println(loginBean.getUsername());
                                    System.out.println(loginBean.getPassword());
                                    return "success";
                                }

                            }
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Is this happening when you first land on the login page, or after you submit the form?

Comment: LoginBean show follow bean standard i.e it should have default constructor and getter/setter

Answer (score 1):

Here , you have to replace as below ,

```
@ModelAttribute("login")LoginBean loginBean
```

To

```
@ModelAttribute("LoginBean")LoginBean loginBean
```

This will work fine.......

Answer (score 0):

If `LoginBean` has two fields with getter and setter: `username`  and `password`, then remove the `@ModelAttribute("login")` annotation, because: the `LoginBean` is not a attribute but a command object.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that it is happening when you submit the page. If that is the case then you have to replace - -

```
@ModelAttribute("login")LoginBean loginBean
                      By
@ModelAttribute("login") LoginBean login
System.out.println(login.getUsername());
System.out.println(login.getPassword());
```

I think it will work then. I had a similar issue and resolved that with above approach.